# itextSharp SetField Performance (vs activePDF Toolkit)

Tags: c#, itext, toolkit

I have been using the activePDF Toolkit for quite a while but would like to switch my solution over to iTextSharp. I am comparing the performance of one versus the other and find that iTextSharp is slower than activePDF when filling form fields on a PDF. Here is the code I am using for iTextSharp:

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(template);
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, memoryStream);
    pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
    AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

    foreach (Field f in fields)
        pdfFormFields.SetField(f.Name,f.Value);
}
```

It is only milliseconds slower per form, but that adds up when you process hundreds to thousands of forms when creating a single PDF. I was hoping there might be a different way to set the value of fields, but I don't see one (I took a look at AcroFields.cs as well).

Anyone have thoughts about this?

Comment: Does activePDF also create appearances and flatten the form afterwards?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the concept of "appearances", but my solution with activePDF does do flattening. I tried iTextSharp without the flattening and the results were about the same

Comment: If you are filling the same form over and over again, you can use the `setFieldCache()` method as shown in [`Subscribe`](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=161) example. This will keep a cache of the properties of the fields, thus avoiding having to read the template over and over again.

Comment: Some of the templates are repeated, but a majority aren't. I'll see if I can use the cache on those that do repeat and if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, that did speed things up a bit. It has brought me closer to the speed of activePDF, but not close enough yet.

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably never hit the same speed.  ActivePDF Toolkit is native 32-bit and 64-bit code with a .NET wrapper.  We can (and do) always find ways to tweak and increase performance but managed code is at the mercy of the CLR.